# fasttext ROC and AUC issue for binary classifications

Tags: python, roc, auc, precision-recall, fasttext

I tried to calculate ROC and AUC for fasttext trained model but I always get the error `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [40, 200]`

My testing code as follow:

```
def split_df(data):
     count_vect = CountVectorizer()
     print('Loading data ...')
     labels, texts = ([], [])
     for line in data:
       label, text = line.split(' ', 1)
       labels.append(label)
       texts.append(text)

     trainDF = pd.DataFrame()
     trainDF['label'] = labels
     trainDF['text'] = texts

     # to fit the text in the dataframe
     # You have to do some encoding before using fit. As it known fit() does not accept Strings.
     count_vect = CountVectorizer()
     matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(trainDF['text'])
     encoder = LabelEncoder()
     targets = encoder.fit_transform(trainDF['label'])

     # split into train/test sets
     trainX, testX, trainy, testy = train_test_split(
            matrix, targets, test_size=0.2)

     return trainX, testX, trainy, testy

test_sentences = open('testing_proj.valid').readlines()

model = fasttext.load_model("model_testing_proj.bin")
trainX, testX, trainy, testy = split_df(test_sentences)

# label the data
labels, probabilities = model.predict([re.sub('\n', ' ', sentence) 
                                                     for sentence in test_sentences])
auc = roc_auc_score(testy, probabilities)
print('ROC AUC=%.3f' % (auc))

# convert fasttext multilabel results to a binary classifier (probability of TRUE)
labels = list(map(lambda x: x == ['__label__nonsec-report'] or x == ['__label__sec-report'], labels))
probabilities = [probability[0] if label else (1-probability[0]) 
                 for label, probability in zip(labels, probabilities)]

auc = roc_auc_score(testy, probabilities)
print('ROC AUC=%.3f' % (auc))
```

**Edited**
The problem that I could not solve is calculate ROC & AUC and that because i could not figure out how to represent the data into data frame and the testing split size should be same as the predicted probabilities list.The `train_test_split` method did not accept splitting .txt files and that is why is used to convert the validation data into data frame format. This cost me the error because I need to make sure the size of the testing split is same as the predicted probabilities (this is my understanding for the error, correct me if I am wrong?).

The complete traceback info as follow:

```
Warning : `load_model` does not return WordVectorModel or SupervisedModel any more, but a `FastText` object which is very similar.
Loading data ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sultan/brclassifications/fasttext_classifications/temp_test.py", line 51, in <module>
    auc = roc_auc_score(testy, probabilities)
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 542, in roc_auc_score
    return _average_binary_score(partial(_binary_roc_auc_score,
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_base.py", line 77, in _average_binary_score
    return binary_metric(y_true, y_score, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 330, in _binary_roc_auc_score
    fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(y_true, y_score,
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 913, in roc_curve
    fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py", line 693, in _binary_clf_curve
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)
  File "/home/sultan/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 319, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError("Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of"
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [40, 200]
```

Comment: If you add the full error (with traceback info) to your question, it will be clearer which line(s) of code are involved. Also, even though your end goal is a plot, if trying to get over a specific exception, showing the barest minimum code to trigger the exception may also help people address the blocking-problem (without having to understand your entire setup).

Comment: I have updated the questions, and sorry it is not plotting, it is calculating AUC and ROC.

Answer (score 0):

At some point in your code, your are passing 2 vectors:

1. It contains 20 observations
2. It contains 400 observations

Therefore, the function won’t know how to coordinate those sample.

The error should be when you compare predictions with real values at some point.

May I suggest to use the `plot_roc_curve()` function.

You could import it `from sklearn.metrics import plot_roc_curve()`.

Then, if you are on Jupyter and press `shift + tab` keys, an explanation on how to use the function will appear.